# SSL support Docker Swarm with Nginx

Tags: ssl, docker, nginx

I am attempting to setup SSL with Nginx running on a docker swarm but have run into an issue. Everything looks correct but any request I make just hangs until I get a 502. I made sure to expose port 443 in my compose file. Here is the nginx error I am getting:

```
*7 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.255.0.2, server: subdomain.mysite.com, request: "GET /api-v1/user-login HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://10.0.0.6:5051/api-v1/user-login", host: "subdomain.mysite.com"
```

Here is the relevant piece of my nginx default.conf:

```
ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1;

upstream siteStage {
  ip_hash;
  server siteStage:5051;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 ;
  server_name subdomain.mysite.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /path/provided.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/client.key;
  ssl_client_certificate /path/ca.crt;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_verify_client      off;

  location / {
    proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/client.pem;
    proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/client.key;
    proxy_ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    proxy_ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    proxy_pass https://siteStage/;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was my nginx config. Here is how I finally got it to work:

```
# No upstream

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  server_name subdomain.mysite.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /path/provided.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/client.key;

  if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://siteStage:5051/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
  }
}
```

Comment: So the solution was to contact the docker service via http instead of https?

Comment: @mjb2kmn Yea, that an I'd added the proxy headers, removed the proxy certificate, and removed the client certificate which the nginx tutorial has you put in those last 2.